# Is it possible to iterate over this column as an array(and would it be more efficient)?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

After much research and digging through the meager documentation on google apps script this was the only way I've found to iterate over data from a google sheet. Does anybody know if columns can be converted to arrays and iterated upon more efficiently? The function below works but is not very fast.

```
function Recon(){

  var currentValue;

  var countAdvice = 0;

  var lastValue = null;

  var lastLine;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Transactions");

  var rowCount = spreadsheet.getLastRow();

  spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard")

  spreadsheet.getRange('D1').setValue(rowCount);

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Transactions");


  for(var i = rowCount; i>1; i--){


    currentValue = spreadsheet.getRange('G'+i).getValue();


    if( lastValue != null && currentValue == (lastValue*(-1))){

      spreadsheet.getRange('M'+i).setValue('okay');
      spreadsheet.getRange('K'+i).setValue(currentValue);
      spreadsheet.getRange('L'+i).setValue(lastValue);


      spreadsheet.getRange('M'+lastLine).setValue('okay');
      countAdvice++;


    }

    lastValue = currentValue;

    lastLine = i;

}

    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard")


    spreadsheet.getRange('E1').setValue(countAdvice);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call getRange() you are making a HTTP call, which then has to go out, fetch the data and then parse it. It is best practice to fetch data in large datasets once and then also write once.

There are some other issues in your code:

- the variable spreadsheet is changing its reference, once it is transaction, then it is dashboard. Instead of doing this, create 2 separate variables, one for each sheet reference.
- Your for loop is backwards, is there a reason for this?

See below for an approach on how to basically make 1 fetch call and 1 write call.

```
  var transSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Transactions");  
  var allRows = transSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var outputArray = [];

  // run through each row
  allRows.forEach( function(row) {
    var currentValue = row[6]; // column

    // if some condition applies
    if( currentValue == "whatever" ){
      // place values in certain columns in that particular row
      outputArray.push( ["this goes into col K", "this into col L", "this goes into col M" ] )

    } else {
      // place empty values in those columns
      outputArray.push( ["", "", "" ])
    }
  });

  // now the output is ready to be inserted
  var startInsertingAtThisColumn = 7; // G
  var writeOutputToSheet = transSheet.getRange( 1, startInsertingAtThisColumn, outputArray.length, outputArray[0].length ).setValues( outputArray );
```

Reference
- [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this method is much better. I am also trying to add each cell to each previous cell, however, when adding it will always output #NUM!. I have tried using the + operator before the value pulled from the array or Number() but nothing seems to work. It continues to pull the value as String I believe. I have a var runningBalance that is initially set to zero and then the cell value is added to that for each row.

Comment: I need more information on that. But normally you should be able to just add them to the `var counter = 0` and then, in the forEach you add the value like this 
`counter += currentValue`

Comment: My header row was messing it up from the beginning but when I simplified it as you suggested it worked. Thanks again!